# How to convert KMZ file to KML using javascript?

Tags: javascript, kml, kmz

In am writing `JavaScript` code for adding kmz,kml and csv file from local folder.All the files will be displayed/added on esri Maps.I am able to add kml and csv, but not kmz.I dont want to include full zip/unzip code or library into my code.I dont need that all.Only need a small code for converting kmz to kml.

Also I don't want to store any unzipped or converted file(which will be kml) in any local folder.

Just want to read the contents and pass it to my add_kml() function on the fly. 
Only want to extract the contents from kmz file which will be kml.
The code available everywhere is to store the extracted file in some folder.I dont want that.

function unZipAndProcessKMZ(blob)
        {
             zip.createReader(new zip.BlobReader(blob),
            function(reader) 
            {// get all entries from the zip
             reader.getEntries( function(entries) 
                                                        { parseTransformKMZ(entries);}
                                                          );
          }, 
             function(error) {/* onerror callback */ }
          );
        }

```
    function parseTransformKMZ(entries) 
    {
        //Step 1: find doc.kml
        var docKMLentry = findFileByName(entries, '.kml', false);
        console.log('in Parse file: ', docKMLentry.filename);       
        docKMLentry.getData(    new zip.BlobWriter('text/xml'),
        function(kmlText) 
        {

    var fileReader = new FileReader();

                                       fileReader.addEventListener("loadend",  function() 
{                                                docKML = fileReader.result;

if (typeof docKML == 'string') {
docKML = ( new window.DOMParser() ).parseFromString(docKML, "text/xml");
                       }   
    var geojson = toGeoJSON[extension](docKML);                    
            //send data to esri converter
                  feats = geojson.features;
                 if (!feats || (feats.length === 0)) {
                 alert("No features found");
                 return;
        }     convertTo_esri();
```

});

Comment: I am struggling with code for unzipping the contents.Because the only solution I got here is to unzip it to kml.But after unzipping the contents kml file is getting added to my local folder.Which I dont want.

Comment: also I tried using php code to unzip kmz file.The code is very small compared to js code.But need to use js.Again with tha php code file is getting saved in local folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the solution-
simply passed blob object taken as input file to the zip.blobReader function in zip.js

Comment: could you please share the final version of the code? i'm not sure i got how zip.blobReader works